# Automatically setting cursor on a text form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cursor

Is it possible to automatically set the cursor in a text form field so that the user can start typing without first clicking on the text field (or pressing tab)

I assume with Javascript / JQuery it might be possible?

Comment: `document.getElementById('SomeTextField').focus()`

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `autofocus` attribute :

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

Comment: input is a void element ;)

Comment: @A. Wolff : thank you , `<button>`s are on my mind)))

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is

IN jQuery:

```
$('#YOUR_ELEMENT_ID').focus();
```

IN JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.getElementById('YOUR_ELEMENT_ID').focus();
```